# Script to show USD amount in BTC real time in WEBSITE

Tags: javascript

I need help with this endeavour: On a website I need the equivalent of 300$ or 500$ to be shown as BTC price (in relation to a well-known exchange api), in "real-time", to be updated every time the page is refreshed, as text. I would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction as where to start with achieving this.

Thank you in advance, you're awesome!

Comment: Have you some kind of api in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CoinGecko API to get the current price of BTC every time the page reloads. [Here is the documentation.](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api) I personally use it for projects when I need to get the price of a coin.

Do this by [sending an HTTP request](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/) to the CoinGecko API.

When you get the BTC price, just divide 300 or 500 by the BTC price and you'll get the value of $300 or $500 in BTC.

Example:

$300 / $37000 = 0.0081 BTC

or

$500 / $37000 = 0.0135 BTC

Comment: Thanks for your answear, first of all, i should do this in javascript rigth?

Comment: Yes, you should use JavaScript.

Comment: You're awesome man, I think my last question right now would be how to "print" (how to show) the resulted price on the website as text. I'm using wordpress and building with WPBakery Page Builder. Thank you in advance for your help!